# Can a Subset be considered an Element for Field Axioms

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, real-numbers

I have the subset $L\subset \Bbb Q$ that is  Dedekind cut.

I want to prove that $L+(-L)=0$

I want to do this using the field axiom of Additive Inverse, but Additive Inverse specifically deals with elements.

Can I consider subset $L$ as an element for these purposes?

Edit/JL: This question superficially looks a bit strange, confused even. But the comments make it clear that in the context the OP encountered this question the subsets are those occurring in Dedekind cuts. And the addition is the addition of Dedekind cuts as opposed to the usual addition of subsets of an additive group. This makes a huge difference IMHO.

Comment: What do you even mean by L+(-L)=0?  Under the normal definition of "set addition", when you have a + function on the elements, that would be the set of all sums of elements of the two sets.....then what do you mean by it equalling 0?  0 is not a set (Unless you mean the empty set....or the set of the 0 element....)

Comment: https://imgur.com/f3ucZPO. Problem 3 here. We are dealing with Dedekind Cuts. So L is a subset of D.

Answer (score 4):

In the case of Dedekind cuts, the answer is yes. The real numbers are ***defined*** to be subsets of the rational numbers with certain properties.

In turn, $\Bbb Q$ can be thought as sets of pairs of integers, which themselves can be thought as sets of pairs of natural numbers, which in turn can be thought of as sets.

The whole idea behind having the notion of a set, is that a collection of mathematical objects can be a mathematical object in its own rights. And mathematical objects can be elements of other mathematical objects, in particular a field.

---

To verify that $L+(-L)=0$ you need recall that in this context $0$ is itself a particular subset of $\Bbb Q$ as a real number, and use the definitions as to what are $-L$ and how $+$ is defined between these sets.

Answer (score 1):

As Alan suggests in his comment, under the ordinary understanding of the notation $S+T$, where $S$ and $T$ are subsets of (say) a field $D$, $S+T$ is defined to be the *set* of all sums, one element from $S$ and one element from $T$. Now if your set $L$ is a singleton, there is only one way of choosing an element of $L$, similarly of $-L$, and the unique result would be zero, so that in this very restricted case, $L+(-L)=\{0\}$. However, if $L$ is a finite set with $n$ elements, then $L+(-L)$ would have perhaps as many as $n^2-n+1$ elements. Take the case $L=\{1,3,7\}\subset\Bbb R$. The set of all differences is $\{0,\pm2,\pm4,\pm6\}$.

If this isn’t what you meant by “$L+(-L)$”, then you’ll have to be very explicit about what you did mean.